# PGFplots: Tweak two plots to achieve equal heights

Tags: pgfplots

The heights of the plots in the following example are slightly differ. Can one get them to equal heights *without* `\resizebox` (would mess with fontsize) or setting the height in absolute quantities.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=major,
  xmin=-3,
  xmax=+5,
  ymin=-0.25,
  xlabel=$y$,
  ylabel={$f(y)$},
  width=.5\linewidth
]
  \addplot[samples=101, domain=-3:5] ({x}, {2*sqrt(abs(x-1))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{.05\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=major,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel={$y_a(x)$},
  width=.5\linewidth
]
  \addplot[domain=0:2] {1 - (1 - x/2)^2};
  \addplot[domain=2:4] {1 + (x - 2)^2/4};
  \addplot[domain=2:4, dotted] {1};
  \addplot[domain=4:6, dotted] {1 + (x - 4)^2/4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: They look pretty equal to me. You mean the curve heights in the plots? See it by removing `\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{.05\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the heights were different was due to the `xlabels`. The characters `x` and `y` have different depth. So one way would be to add a `\strut` to both of them as I have done in the MWE:

[image]

Alternatively, you could use `x\vphantom{y}` in the second plot.  This solution of course is dependent on the actual labels for the plots.

### Notes:

- You were also using more than a `\linewidth`. I have corrected that below.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=major,
  xmin=-3,
  xmax=+5,
  ymin=-0.25,
  xlabel=$y\strut$,
  ylabel={$f(y)$},
  width=.48\linewidth
]
  \addplot[samples=101, domain=-3:5, blue, thick] ({x}, {2*sqrt(abs(x-1))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill%\hspace{.05\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=major,
  xlabel=$x\strut$,
  ylabel={$y_a(x)$},
  width=.48\linewidth
]
  \addplot[domain=0:2, red, thick] {1 - (1 - x/2)^2};
  \addplot[domain=2:4, red, thick] {1 + (x - 2)^2/4};
  \addplot[domain=2:4, red, thick, dotted] {1};
  \addplot[domain=4:6, red, thick, dotted] {1 + (x - 4)^2/4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
%\hfill\null{}% <-- uncomment if you don't want second plot all the way to the right
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Uuuh, thanks for noting the `linewidth` type ... and I also solved the corresponding ODE the wrong way ;-)